# Signs of inverse of M0-matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

Let $A$ be an invertible $n \times n$ real matrix where the diagonal elements are non-negative and the off-diagonal elements are non-positive. Is there anything that can be said about the signs of the elements of the inverse, $A^{-1}$?

I believe that we can say something about the signs of $A^{-1}$ if the diagonal elements are *strictly* positive. Then $A$ is an [M-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix), and so an equivalent condition is that $A$ is inverse-positive, i.e. all the elements of $A^{-1}$ are non-negative. But here the inequality for the diagonal elements is weak not strict, and I haven't found any similar equivalences for this class of matrices ([Fieldler and Pták](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/100526/CzechMathJ_12-1962-3_6.pdf) refer to this class as the $K_0$-class).

Comment: Have you tried the $2\times 2$ case? Maybe it provides some insight. I feel that a lot will depend on the sign of the determinant of the matrix. By the way, you can simplify your question by noticing that $A = (A^{-1})^{-1}$, so you could just ask I have $A$ such that .... then what happens to $A^{-1}$?

Comment: Thanks I have simplified the question as you have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, nothing can be said about the signs of the elements of $A^{-1}$. They can be all negative, all positive, or consisting of positives, negatives and even zeroes. E.g.
\begin{aligned}
\pmatrix{3&-1&-1\\ -1&3&-1\\ -1&-1&3}^{-1}
&=\frac14\pmatrix{2&1&1\\ 1&2&1\\ 1&1&2},\\
\pmatrix{2&-1&-1\\ -2&2&-1\\ -2&-2&2}^{-1}
&=\frac{1}{10}\pmatrix{-2&-4&-3\\ -6&-2&-4\\ -8&-6&-2},\\
\pmatrix{2&-2&-2\\ -2&2&-1\\ -2&-2&1}^{-1}
&=\frac{1}{12}\pmatrix{0&-3&-3\\ -2&1&-3\\ -4&-4&0}.
\end{aligned}
But surely, if $A$ is an invertible M-matrix according to the usual definition (but **not** according to your definition, because the usual definition of M-matrix requires all eigenvalues of $A$ to have nonnegative real parts), then $A^{-1}$ is a nonnegative matrix.

Comment: Thanks. So an M-matrix has positive diagonal elements and nonpositive off-diagonal elements but the converse isn't true.